# Laravel 4 Ajax request always returns error

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-4

I have implemented a jQuery ajax call to a controller in Laravel 4. But it always seems to return an error.

**My Ajax Call**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/test",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        'data': data,
        'data2': data2
    },
    success: function(e) {
        console.log("Success");
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log("Fail");
    }
});
```

**The Controller**

```
public function doSomething(){    
    $data = $_POST['data' ];
    $data2 = $_POST[ 'data2' ];
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;

    DataHelper::addData($userId,$data,$data2);
    $response = "Success";
    return Response::json("Job Done");
}
```

Once the Ajax call is run, `console.log("Fail");` is displayed. But when I check the response to the request the json string "Job Done" has been returned.
Actually I noticed this now, the response is []"Job Done" instead of "Job Done"

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is waiting for json format, how about changing your response for something like:

```
return Response::json([
    'status' => 'Job Done'
], 200);
```

Comment: I tried this but still doesn't work. Is there a way to find out the error? I used Chrome and went to inspect element and in the network tab, the request shows that the "Job Done" string is returned. But still "Fail" is logged in console

Comment: What are the values on your request's "Accept" header  and your response's "Content-Type" header? (use Chrome's tools)

Comment: Response header Content-Type:application/json..
Request header Accept:*/*